Audio Recording Resets When Receiving New Messages in Flutter Chat App Using Firebase and StreamBuilder
I'm working on a chat app in Flutter where I'm using Firebase to fetch and display messages in real-time. For this, I'm utilizing a StreamBuilder to update the chat room whenever a new message is sent.
The issue I'm facing is that whenever I’m in the middle of recording a voice message or playing one, and a new message arrives, the entire widget rebuilds due to the StreamBuilder and the audio (whether it's recording or playback) restarts from the beginning.
How can I prevent the audio recording or playback from being interrupted when a new message comes in? Is there a way to avoid rebuilding the widget completely while still listening to the stream for updates?
Any suggestions or best practices for this would be great. Thanks!
Using a Key to prevent rebuilding specific widgets: I tried assigning a Key to the audio recording and playback widget to prevent them from being rebuilt during new messages. However, this didn’t solve the issue, as the whole widget tree still gets rebuilt when a new message is detected by the StreamBuilder.
Extracting the audio recording/playback functionality into a separate widget: I attempted to extract the audio features into a different widget and managed its state separately, but this didn’t prevent the rebuild either. The moment a new message arrives, the StreamBuilder triggers a rebuild, and the audio resets.
Using StreamBuilder only for specific parts of the UI: I tried to limit the StreamBuilder to only rebuild certain parts of the UI, such as the message list. While it helped reduce unnecessary rebuilds of some parts of the app, it still didn’t solve the problem entirely because the parent widget gets rebuilt when new data comes in.
Persisting audio state manually: I tried saving the current state of the audio (like the position in playback or the recording state) and manually restoring it after the rebuild, but this feels hacky and still introduces a delay or minor glitches in the user experience.
Using StreamBuilder alongside setState: I attempted to selectively update the UI using setState rather than allowing the entire StreamBuilder to trigger a rebuild, but this still didn’t completely prevent the interruption
